# How to get first href link of li in a ul list in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following list

```
 <ul class="tabs">
 <li><a href="testlink.php">First link</a></li>  
 <li><a href="testlink2.php">Second link</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I would like to grab the href for the first link. This link needs to be in a var link so I can use it to dynamically retrieve a page content.
Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [:first](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
var url = $("ul.tabs a:first").attr("href");
```

Or the [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
var url = $("ul.tabs a:eq(0)").attr("href");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(function() {
    var href = $('ul.tabs').find('a').slice(0,1).attr('href');
});
```

This is pretty fast, if you're after performance try to avoid Sizzle selectors:

http://jsperf.com/selector-sizzle-vs-methods

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know, 42% performance loss is not something to be ignored. I'll try to provide both strategies in my future answers (we're already doing something similar for LINQ after all). +1 for fastest solution.

Answer (score 0):

simple as

```
var link = $(".tabs li:first a").attr("href");
```

Comment: Nope, `tabs` is a class, not an id. You're looking for `.tabs`.