# dynamically href link to next sibling on ul tree

Tags: javascript

Im using Javascript, but not Jquery or other frameworks.  Id rather lose the weight as there are only a few functions in the program.  I am trying something a bit like this guy: [Get the next href in a list in another file with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558126/get-the-next-href-in-a-list-in-another-file-with-jquery)

I will have a load of separate HTML pages but they will be linked to their Siblings.  I am basically looking for a dynamic way to do previous and next links for each page, to link to their siblings.

For example:

```
<ul><li>1
    <ul><li>a</li>
        <li>b</li></ul></li>
    <li>2
    <ul><li>c</li>
        <li>d</li></ul></li>
<ul>
```

If Im on page b the next will take me to c.  And if I'm on c the same button will take me to d etc.

I should be able to generate the href for the next page using something form this page: [How to get first href link of li in a ul list in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607934/how-to-get-first-href-link-of-li-in-a-ul-list-in-jquery) 
For example

```
var url = $("ul a:eq(0)").attr("href");
```

But how would I find some sort of .this in the < ul > tree the page Im on right now, so I know to go to the next link?  Is there some sort of find this html on ul ?

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem down:

1. Analyse what page you're on (possibly using the [window.location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location))
2. Find that node in the menu
3. Find the next and previous nodes
4. Generate your links

Comment: yes - I am lost on how to do step 1.  Once I do that maybe I could get to step 2 maybe not.  3&4 I should be able...

Comment: Im a complete novice at js but thats a big help.  I didnt know the window location existed.  Hopefully after a while I can get y head around it.  Thanks